# Touchpad problems worsening over time!

Tags: touchpad, cursor

Thought that I would add some information regarding laptop touhpad issues.  I have a Samsung R530 laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.  There has always been issues with my touchpad; it would start by being erratic, then would move only small amounts at a time and occasionally it would correct, sometimes I would need a reboot.  Now since the upgrade things are getting rather strange! Initially the touchpad worked great, then it reverted back to its operation problems as with ubuntu 11.10; now the cursor randomly freezes and the only option is to reboot.  It seems that over time the problem is getting worse, is it possible that the problem could worsen over time? is there any hope of a fix? I also have a Compaq Presario running Ubuntu 12.04 with no cursor problems as yet, it has a wireless mouse attached.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off the feature that attempts to [disable your touchpad while you're typing](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-disabletouchpad.html)?

Comment: Yes Jacob I have already turned that feature off.